# Building android projects with TeamCity - testing and code coverage issues

Tags: android, ant, teamcity, code-coverage, emma

I'm working on a project  consisting of both .NET code and android java projects. We're trying to get both types of projects working in one TeamCity environment.

The .NET projects are being tested through some NUnit projects, and we use DotCover to produce coverage reports and all seems swell. Now, the android/java projects are being built using ant runners, and we've got some build-scripts both for the production and for the test projects, and the problem is, it seems, the creation of the java coverage reports.

We've created a build step with the following ant targets:

```
clean emma debug install test
```

The build step is set to have "Emma coverage runner" enabled (with the option "Include source files in the coverage data" checked).

An error occures when running the build step, stating the following in the log snippet (full log file is attached). Another important issue is that the android/java unit tests doesn't appear in the overall statistics of the build.

Here's the log snippit:

```
[16:37:52]: [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
[16:37:55]: [subant] -pre-compile
[16:37:55]: [subant] -compile (1s)
[16:37:55]: [-compile] do-only-if-manifest-hasCode (1s)
[16:37:55]: [do-only-if-manifest-hasCode] sequential (1s)
[16:37:55]: [sequential] if (1s)
[16:37:55]: [if] Adding debug=true parameter to javac task
[16:37:55]: [if] javac
[16:37:55]: [if] Compiling 1 source file to C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\MyAndroidProject\bin\classes
[16:37:55]: [if] EMMA: Instrumenting classes
[16:37:55]: [EMMA: Instrumenting classes] EMMA commandline: [-ix, -*Test*, -cp, C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\MyAndroidProject\bin\classes, -m, overwrite]
[16:37:55]: [EMMA: Instrumenting classes] EMMA: processing instrumentation path ...
[16:37:56]: [EMMA: Instrumenting classes] EMMA: instrumentation path processed in 265 ms
[16:37:56]: [EMMA: Instrumenting classes] EMMA: [167 class(es) instrumented, 0 resource(s) copied]
[16:37:56]: [EMMA: Instrumenting classes] EMMA: metadata merged into [C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.em] {in 15 ms}
[16:37:56]: [if] if
[16:37:56]: [if] echo
[16:37:56]: [echo] Instrumenting classes from C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\MyAndroidProject\bin/classes...
[16:37:56]: [if] emma
[16:37:56]: [emma] com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [OUT_IO_FAILURE] exception occurred while writing output file [C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.em]:
[16:37:56]: [do-only-if-manifest-hasCode] The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:655: com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [OUT_IO_FAILURE] exception occurred while writing output file [C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.em]:
[16:37:56]: [subant] The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:602: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:655: com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [OUT_IO_FAILURE] exception occurred while writing output file [C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.em]:
[16:37:56]: [Step 1/18] EMMA: Create Report (4s)
[16:38:00]: [EMMA: Create Report] Unable to find C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.ec, cannot create EMMA report
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] Process exited with code 1
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] Ant output:
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] Caused by: java.io.IOException: cannot merge new data into [C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.em]: created by another EMMA version [0.0.0]
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at com.vladium.emma.data.DataFactory.persist(DataFactory.java:593)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at com.vladium.emma.data.DataFactory.persist(DataFactory.java:71)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] at com.vladium.emma.instr.InstrProcessorST._run(InstrProcessorST.java:753)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] ... 71 more
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] Total time: 6 seconds
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] Publishing artifacts
[16:38:00]: [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.ec, C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.em, C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.txt, C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage\coverage.zip]
[16:38:00]: [Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path coverage.ec not found
[16:38:00]: [Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path coverage.txt not found
[16:38:00]: [Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path coverage/coverage.zip not found
[16:38:00]: [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] Failed to extract Emma coverage statistics from the coverage.txt, due to error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\BuildAgent\work\c588ac2d935670cb\coverage.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
[16:38:00]: [Step 1/18] Step Test Smart Client - Unit tests (Ant) failed
```

Does anyone have an idea to what the problem might be?

By the way, when I run the targets directly from a command line, the reports are built without any problems.

Regards,
   Per

Answer (score 6):

The EMMA version used by the Android SDK is older than the one used by the Sonar EMMA plugin.

It seems the way code coverage is encoded changed between the versions, that's why Sonar can't recognize the format.

Fortunately, someone came up with a transcoder. The issue is described in more detail here:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1356

The java code for the aforementioned transcoder can also be downloaded from there.

You just have to transcode all the .em and .ec files before running Sonar on them and it should read them fine - tried and tested.

Comment: You have been fantastically helpful today!

Comment: It was hard enough figuring that out, I don't want anyone else to share my fate :)

Comment: Awesome, this was very helpful and worked perfectly: I copied EmmaTranscoder.class into the same directory as the coverage files and executed `java -cp . EmmaTranscoder coverage.[ec|em]`